# Using UIPageControl Without UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uipagecontrol

I'm currently using swipe gestures to switch between view controllers and I'm wondering if I can implement a uipagecontrol on each view controller without using a uiscrollview.

Here is how I'm going from one view controller to another:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.title = @"Home";

    UIBarButtonItem *settingsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"\u2699" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(settingsButtonPressed:)];
    [settingsButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:24], UITextAttributeFont,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = settingsButton;

    UIBarButtonItem *systemAction = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(showMenu)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = systemAction;

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft:)];
    swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
}

- (IBAction)swipeLeft:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    HomeTwo *homeTwo = [[HomeTwo alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeTwo" bundle:nil];
    homeTwo.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:homeTwo animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIPageControl` is just a view so you can certainly add one to each view controllers view and then set the current page to an appropriate value.

Comment: Could you let me know some more details with some sample code?

Comment: @Dinesh, if you have a specific problem you should create a new question and show the code you have. The code is basically just `currentPage`.

Comment: My problem is the same as this thread. I want to use UIPageControl to switch between views without using a UIScrollView. I have 2 child view controllers. I would like to know how to load the views.

Comment: Use a gesture and a view animation. The page control is only used to display the current page number, not to transition.

Comment: So how do I load a view. I mean to say that I want a specific view to be seen on starting the app. I am not sure how to use this view animation. I used `pageControl.currentPage = 0;` but I do not see it on loading. I added both the views as children to the view which has `pageControl'.

Comment: Create a view instance (probably using a view controller) and add it as a subview. You should really create a new question...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45400/discussion-between-dinesh-and-wain)